# How to find the minimum value of the absolute value under this trigonometric function relationship?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Given `f[x_]=2Sin[x](Sqrt[3]Cos[x]-Sin[x])`,

and `f[x1]f[x2]==-3`,

find the minimum of `Abs[x1-x2]`

The following method cannot solve this problem:

```
Minimize[{RealAbs[x1 - x2], 
  4 Sin[x1] (Sqrt[3] Cos[x1] - Sin[x1]) Sin[
     x2] (Sqrt[3] Cos[x2] - Sin[x2]) == -3}, {x1, x2}]
```

Comment: `NMinimize` rapidly finds something suspiciously close to Pi/2. `Simplify[Reduce[RealAbs[x1 - x2]==Pi/2&&...]]` rapidly finds solutions. `Simplify[Reduce[RealAbs[x1 - x2]<Pi/2&&...]]` rapidly returns `False` but with a warning.

Comment: It is best to find the exact value.

Comment: You used `Sqrt[x]` in the first line code and then inside `Minimize` you used `Sqrt[3]`. What is the correct version of the equation? With `Sqrt[x]` or `Sqrt[3]`?

Comment: The correct is Sqrt[3]

Answer (score 3):

My answer in this image. I think,  minimum of $|x_1 - x_2|$ equal to $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

[image]

Comment: Which software is used to edit the formulas and procedures in the picture?

Answer (score 2):

Considering the condition:

```
cond[x1_,x2_]=4  Sin[x1]  (Sqrt[3]  Cos[x1] - Sin[x1])  Sin[
  x2]  (Sqrt[3]  Cos[x2] - Sin[x2])
```

we note that we have symmetries:

```
cond[x1,x2]==cond[x2,x1]== cond[x1+ n1 Pi,x2+n2 Pi]
```

The target function also has symmetries (c some constant):

```
tar[x1,x2]===tar[x2,x1]==tar[-x1,-x2]== tar[x1+c,x2+c]
```

Therefore, we will have multiple solutions:

```
sol[x1,x2],sol[x2,x1],sol[x1+n1 Pi,x2+ n2 Pi ]
```

NMinimize can deliver one of those solutions:

```
NMinimize[{RealAbs[x1 - x2], 
  4  Sin[x1]  (Sqrt[3]  Cos[x1] - Sin[x1])  Sin[
     x2]  (Sqrt[3]  Cos[x2] - Sin[x2]) == -3}, {x1, x2}]

{1.5707, {x1 -> 3.66517, x2 -> 2.09446}}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the constraint be ` 4  Sin[x1]  (Sqrt[x1]  Cos[x1] - Sin[x1])  Sin[
     x2]  (Sqrt[x2]  Cos[x2] - Sin[x2]) == -3` (not Sqrt[3]...)

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann   Where do you see Sqrt[3]?

Comment: See constraint: 4  Sin[x1]  ( **Sqrt[3]**  Cos[x1] - Sin[x1])  Sin[
     x2]  (**Sqrt[3]**  Cos[x2] - Sin[x2]) == -3 in your last `NMinimize`

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be simplified by noting that $f(x)$ is equivalent to:

```
f[x_] := 2  Sin[2 x + Pi/6] - 1
```

This can be seen by:

```
TrigExpand[f[x]] // Simplify
```

which yields: 2 (Sqrt[3] Cos[x] - Sin[x]) Sin[x]

This is $\pi$ periodic. Let $g(x,y)=f(x) f(y)$: then we only need consider domain $[0,\pi]^2$. -3 happens to be a minimum in this domain and the solution to the problem involves evaluating 2 points. I will illustrate as possible and compare with [`NMinimize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinimize.html):

```
g[x_, y_] := f[x] f[y]
val = {x, 
    y} /. {ToRules[
     Reduce[g[x, y] == -3 && 0 < x < Pi && 0 < y < Pi, {x, y}]]};

Show[Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.4]], 
 Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> Blue], 
 Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.02], 
   Point[{#1, #2, g[#1, #2]} & @@@ val]}]]
Abs[#1 - #2] & @@@ val
```

[image]

This illustrates fundamental domain and points where $g(x,y)=-3$.  The minimum is $\pi/2$.

This is consistent with numerical assessment:

```
Sqrt[NMinimize[{(x - y)^2, g[x, y] == -3}, {x, y}][[1]]]
```

which yields: 1.5708

Answer (score 1):

We may replace `RealAbs[x1-x2]` by `(x1-x2)^2` since the minimums of these are attained for the same values of `x1` and `x2` . Making use of periodicity of `Sin` and `Cos`, one obtains

```
Minimize[{(x1-x2)^2,4 Sin[x1] (Sqrt[3] Cos[x1]-Sin[x1])*
Sin[x2] (Sqrt[3] Cos[x2]-Sin[x2])==-3&&
x1>-Pi&&x1<=Pi&&x2>-Pi&&x2<=Pi},{x1,x2}]//ToRadicals
```

> Minimize::ztest: Unable to decide whether numeric quantities {-4 (<<6>>+2 <<1>> ArcTan[Root[{<<1>>&,<<1>>&,<<1>>&},{<<1>>}]]-ArcTan[Root[{<<3>>},{<<3>>}]]^2),-4 (<<1>>),-4 <<1>>,-4 (ArcTan[<<1>>]^2-<<1>>^2-<<1>>+<<1>>+<<1>>-<<1>>^2),-4 (<<1>>)} are equal to zero. Assuming they are.`{\[Pi]^2/4, {x1 -> -((5 \[Pi])/6), x2 -> -(\[Pi]/3)}}`

Comment: Why do we need to limit the range of x1 and x2 in order to solve for them?

Comment: We may assume those restrictions without loss of generality as explained in the answer. Don't know why `Minimize` fails without `x1>-Pi&&x1<=Pi&&x2>-Pi&&x2<=Pi`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct version of the equation is with `Sqrt[3]`.

I manually found a solution `{x1 -> (7 π)/6, x2 -> (2 π)/3}` which seems to coincide with numeric solution in other answers.

```
Clear[f]

f[x_] := 2 Sin[x] (Sqrt[3] Cos[x] - Sin[x])
f[x1]*f[x2]
{% == -3, x1 - x2} /. {x1 -> (7 π)/6, x2 -> (2 π)/3} // FullSimplify

{x1 -> (7 π)/6, x2 -> (2 π)/3} // N
x1 - x2 /. {x1 -> (7 π)/6, x2 -> (2 π)/3} // N

Clear[f]
```

---

```
4 (Sqrt[3] Cos[x1] - Sin[x1]) Sin[x1] (Sqrt[3] Cos[x2] - Sin[x2]) Sin[x2]

{True, π/2}

{x1 -> 3.66519, x2 -> 2.0944}

1.5708
```

Comment: Can you ground your claim "I manually found a solution `{x1 -> (7 π)/6, x2 -> (2 π)/3}`"?